# Method 'set' in class 'UserInstance' is not assignable to the same method in base 'Model' while using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, express, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I decided to use Typescript in my NodeJs/Express project.
I created models and everything is working fine.
But i am constantly seeing the following typescript error in my model.
**Method 'set' in class 'UserInstance' is not assignable to the same method in base 'Model'**

Here UserInstance is an interface I am creating. Refer to the code snippet below.

./model/user.ts

```
import { Model, Optional, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import dbConn from "../index";
import Site from "./site";

interface UserAttributes {
    id: number;
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    email: string,
    site_id: number,
}

interface UserCreationAttributes
    extends Optional<UserAttributes, 'id'> {}

interface UserInstance
    extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>,
        UserAttributes {
    createdAt?: Date;
    updatedAt?: Date;
}

const User = dbConn.define<UserInstance>(
    'User',
    {
        id: {
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true,
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        lastName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        site_id: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID
        }
    }
);

export default User;
```

I was expecting it to not present any error, as I defined proper interfaces and types for the model.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the warning.
I made the following changes to the configuration and the warning was gone.

- In tsconfig.json

```
"compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es6", //Previousely es2016
}
```

- Updated my IDE.

Apparently the warning had nothing to do with Sequelize.

Comment: I would not accept this as a solution because you are going from es2016 back to es6 (es2015)